# Determine if website collection has RSS feed

Tags: java, python, rss

I have a following problem:

I have a collection of hosts, valid URIs I need to determine if they have rss feed in them or not? 
The biggest issue is that the collection I have is massive, so I can't go through them manually, I need to write a tool in Java or python to be able to go through them and determine if they have rss feeds?

I really need to do this, but it does sound extremely difficult to implement, especially in such large data collection.

If anyone got any ideas of how I might do that or where I can find info for that, is more than welcome to comment down below.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? What are you having trouble with? Are you asking how to write a loop? How to send an HTTP request? How to parse HTML? What `<link>` tags point to RSS feeds?

Answer (score 2):

You can fetch the source of the page and verify if the link element in the "head" has the following format : rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml"

```
<head>
  <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS 2.0" href="http://url_to_test" />
</head>
```